# ng-submit is not working in Laravel PHP framework

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel

everyone, I have another question related to Laravel/AngularJS.

In my mini-project, I have form which user can post question in the form, but when I click `submit` button, there are no requests (from inspect in `Google Chrome`). However, I have a `Log in` interface, the button is working very well. I use the same logic, same html structure. And I am wondering how can I fix this problem.

I have been debugging this for 2 hours, have been Googling for a long time. Please help me out!!

Below are the codes.

// Add question page

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="question.add.tpl">
    <div ng-controller="QuestionAddController" class="question-add container">
        <div class="card">
            <form name="question_add_form" ng-submit="Question.add()">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <label>Title</label>
                    <input type="text"
                           name="title"
                           ng-minlength="5"
                           ng-maxlength="255"
                           ng-model="Question.new_question.title"
                           required>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <label>Description</label>
                    <textarea type="text"
                              name="desc"
                              ng-model="Question.new_question.desc">
                    </textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <button ng-disabled="question_add_form.$invalid"
                            class="primary"
                            type="submit">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

// Service and Controller

```
.service('QuestionService', [
    '$http',
    '$state',
    function ($http, $state) {
        var me = this;
        me.new_question = {};

        me.go_add_question = function () {
            console.log(1);
            $state.go('question.add');
        };

        me.add = function () {
            if (!me.new_question.title)
                return;

            $http.post('/api/question/add', me.new_question)
                .then(function (r) {
                    console.log('r', r);
                    // if (r.data.status) {
                    //     console.log(r.data);
                    //     me.new_question = {};
                    //     $state.go('home');
                    // }
                }, function (e) {
                    console.log('e', e);
                })
        }
    }
])


.controller('QuestionAddController', [
    '$scope',
    'QuestionService',
    function (QuestionService, $scope) {
        $scope.Question = QuestionService;
    }
])
```

in `QuestionService.add()`, there is no "return value" (`console.log('r', r);`) in my browser.

I make sure routes and url are working fine by directly typing the address in browser. Any suggestion will be highly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!!!

Edit:

Besides, the button `Add Question` is not working, too. I have to use `ui-sref` to make it redirect to the target url, will this be the reason why the `submit` button is not working (like I use `ui-sref` not the `ng-submit` to redirect)

// Add question

```
<div class="navbar clearfix">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="fl">
            <div class="navbar-item brand">somethingHere</div>
            <form ng-submit="Question.go_add_question()" id="quick_ask" ng-controller="QuestionAddController">
                <div class="navbar-item">
                    <input ng-model="Question.new_question.title" type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-item">
                    <button ui-sref="question.add" type="submit">Add question</button> <!--ui-sref="question.add"-->
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <blablabla something not important here!!!!>
```

Comment: What does the network tab in the Developer Console show?

Comment: Hi, thanks for reaching out. In `Network->XHR` panel, there in nothing showing up. I am quite confused. I restart my server, still nothing happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your injections in the controller is the wrong order. Should be

```
.controller('QuestionAddController', [
    '$scope',
    'QuestionService',
    function ($scope, QuestionService) {
        $scope.Question = QuestionService;
    }
])
```

EDIT:
The ordering itself does not really matter, but the controller function argument ordering must match the ordering in the array. E.g.

Correct:

```
['QuestionService', 'Service2', '$scope', function(QuestionService, Service2, $scope) { ...
```

Incorrect:

```
['QuestionService', 'Service2', '$scope', function(QuestionService, scope, Service2) { ...
```

The reason to define the controller with array is so that the code can be [minified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming))

Comment: OMG!!!! It works!!!!! So variable like `$scope`, `$http` should always be the first argument? Could you explain a little bit to me!!!!!  Thank you so much!!!!!!!! ^_^